# how to scrape popular posts

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am going to extract popular posts from the following URL "https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts. there is a button defined for popular posts... for extract the posts under this button, I follow the below commands, but I couldn't see any return.

```
 def parse(self, response):
           
    popular_posts = response.css ('button.postFilterInline__RoundedButton-cftabs-1 eYSfqD')
    
    listtitles=[]
    #listpost=[]
    #listreplies=[]
    #listpost_link=[]
    #listauthor=[]
          
    for populars in popular_posts:
        
        all_div_posts = populars.css('.results-post')

        for posts in all_div_posts:
        
           for title in posts.css('.results-post .results-post__title::text').extract():
        
            listtitles.append(title)
           
        yield {"title" : listtitles}
```

Comment: Are you using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)?

Comment: yield is for generators, are you sure you want to yield your result, and not just return it?

Answer (score 0):

That web is build in Js so navigate through html selectors is not a good idea. If you open the network in browser and click on "popular" btn you are going to si a http requests and it response a json.

Try scraping directly https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/popular and proccesing the json :)

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. I am a very beginner in web scraping. Would you please share any link which can guide me on how I can scrap directly " https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/popular " , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Just in case

As Maximo mentioned you can get your information `JSON string`, you can parse it by using the `json.loads()` method.

**Example**

```
import requests, json
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
url = 'https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/popular'
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

posts = json.loads(r.text)

for post in posts:
    print(post['title'])
```

**Output**

```
Ok my Pilker baiters name  these four younger photos  of celebrities  
Ok, I'm  reminiscing for our UK  members 
Sonya refused to get out of bed today  
Walk early this morning LOW SELF ESTEEM CHAT  
Saturday Night “Plenty of fish”
```

---

### Edit

To get more posts you have to call the url with parameter `pageNumber` and loop. Example uses depth of 2 pages.

There is a second loop, that will go to the post url and grab the text of the post. Be aware, that as mentioned you wont get the whole post, cause you have to login.

Please be gentle to the server and use sleep to delay your requests.

**Example**

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
pages = 2
data = []

for page in range(1,pages):
    
    url = 'https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/popular?pageNumber={0}'.format(page)
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

    posts = json.loads(r.text)

    for post in posts:        
        sleep(3.5)
        url = 'https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts/{0}'.format(post['postId'])
        r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        post['postText'] = soup.select_one('div.post-body').get_text('|', strip=True)
    data.append(post)
    
    sleep(0.8)
posts
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. if you check the main URL "https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#poular" you can see a link for "see more posts" but in the json "https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/popular" I can not have all posts. Would you please let me how I can have all posts?

Comment: @TaherehMaghsoudi: Edit my answer and provided additional example - Next steps you should have to figure out yourself ;)

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help. I am going to extract the content of each post. if you see in the JSON file just I cannot see the full text of each post. I used the following codes to request JSON for each post and then extract the whole text of each post but it does not work and has an error.                                                                                                                   url2 = "https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts/[PostID]/[PostTitle]
    
response = requests.get(url2)
json_data = response.json()
print(json_data)

Comment: Very close to it with your approach, but that was not that clearly in your question. So I suggest accept these and ask a new one, cause it needs another solution. Be aware, that you have to login, to get the full texts, there is a "free account paywall" on this website.  I edit my answer a last time, to show the request approach, but recommend to do it in depth with selenium (new question).

Comment: Hi, sorry  I have one more question; I have tried to extract data with login but the code did not work for me. | would so appreciate it if help me to see how I can connect the website through login?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using selenium

To install selenium :

```
pip install selenium webdriver_manager
```

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("ccc-notify-accept").click() # click "I'm ok with that" on coockies prompt

for button in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button"):
    if button.text == "Popular":
        button.click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        break
for post in driver.find_element_by_class_name("results-posts").find_elements_by_class_name("results-post"):
    print(post.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get any output; I had the following error :                                                                
  File "C:\Users\thmag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="ccc-notify-accept"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)